# Class template specializations with shared functionality

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm writing a simple maths library with a template vector type:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Vector {
    public:
        Vector<T, N> &operator+=(Vector<T, N> const &other);
        // ... more operators, functions ...
};
```

Now I want some *additional* functionality specifically for some of these. Let's say I want functions `x()` and `y()` on `Vector<T, 2>` to access particular coordinates. I could create a partial specialization for this:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector<T, 3> {
    public:
        Vector<T, 3> &operator+=(Vector<T, 3> const &other);
        // ... and again all the operators and functions ...
        T x() const;
        T y() const;
};
```

But now I'm repeating everything that already existed in the generic template.

I could also use inheritance. Renaming the generic template to `VectorBase`, I could do this:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Vector : public VectorBase<T, N> {
};

template<typename T>
class Vector<T, 3> : public VectorBase<T, 3> {
    public:
        T x() const;
        T y() const;
};
```

However, now the problem is that all operators are defined on `VectorBase`, so they return `VectorBase` instances. These cannot be assigned to `Vector` variables:

```
Vector<float, 3> v;
Vector<float, 3> w;
w = 5 * v; // error: no conversion from VectorBase<float, 3> to Vector<float, 3>
```

I could give `Vector` an implicit conversion constructor to make this possible:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Vector : public VectorBase<T, N> {
    public:
        Vector(VectorBase<T, N> const &other);
};
```

However, now I'm converting from `Vector` to `VectorBase` and back again. Even though the types are the same in memory, and the compiler might optimize all this away, it feels clunky and I don't really like to have potential run-time overhead for what is essentially a compile-time problem.

Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Why not just make `x()` and `y()` free functions that take the appropriate specialization of `Vector`? E.g. `template<class T> T x(const Vector<T, 3 >& v);`

Comment: Possible, but `v.x()` makes more sense to me than `x(v)`. Also, I'd like to add some specialized constructors, e.g. `Vector<T, 2>(T, T)`, and constructors cannot be free functions.

Comment: No, but you can have functions that return objects by value in the style of `std::make_pair`.

Comment: I'm four days late but I think my answer solve the problem :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to solve this problem. This idiom is used in [boost::operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/operators.htm).

```
template<typename ChildT, typename T, int N>
class VectorBase 
{    
public:
    /* use static_cast if necessary as we know that 'ChildT' is a 'VectorBase' */
    friend ChildT operator*(double lhs, ChildT const &rhs) { /* */ }
    friend ChildT operator*(ChildT const &lhs, double rhs) { /* */ }
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
class Vector : public VectorBase<Vector<T,N>, T, N> 
{
};

template<typename T>
class Vector<T, 3> : public VectorBase<Vector<T, 3>, T, 3>
{
public:
    T x() const {}
    T y() const {}
};

void test()
{
    Vector<float, 3> v;
    Vector<float, 3> w;
    w = 5 * v;
    w = v * 5;
    v.x();

    Vector<float, 5> y;
    Vector<float, 5> z;
    y = 5 * z;
    y = z * 5;
    //z.x(); // Error !!
}
```

Comment: I just revisited this problem after working on something else for a while, and this is indeed the nicest solution. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 4):

Here's something I came up with when playing with C++0x features a while back.  The only C++0x feature used in this is `static_assert`, so you could use Boost to replace that.

Basically, we can use a static size check function that just checks to be sure a given index is less than the size of the vector.  We use a static assert to generate a compiler error if the index is out of bounds:

```
template <std::size_t Index> 
void size_check_lt() const 
{ 
    static_assert(Index < N, "the index is not within the range of the vector"); 
}
```

Then we can provide a `get()` method that returns a reference to the element at a given index (obviously a const overload would be useful too):

```
template <std::size_t Index> 
T& get()
{ 
    size_check_lt<Index>(); return data_[Index]; 
}
```

Then we can write simple accessors like so:

```
T& x() { return get<0>(); }
T& y() { return get<1>(); }
T& z() { return get<2>(); }
```

If the vector has only two elements, you can use x and y but not z.  If the vector has three or more elements you can use all three.

I ended up doing the same thing for constructors--I created constructors for vectors of dimension two, three, and four and added a `size_check_eq` that allowed them to be instantiated only for vectors of dimension two, three, and four, respectively.  I can try and post the complete code when I get home tonight, if anyone is interested.

I dropped the project halfway through, so there might be some huge problem with doing it this way that I didn't run into... at least it's an option to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way ? Using external functions:

```
template <class T>
T& x(Vector<T,2>& vector) { return vector.at<0>(); }

template <class T>
T const& x(Vector<T,2> const& vector) { return vector.at<0>(); }
```

In template programming using external functions is the simplest way to add functionality, simply because of the specialization issue you just encountered.

On the other hand, you could still provide `x`, `y` and `z` for any `N` or perhaps use `enable_if` / `disable_if` features to restrict the scope.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can get around the typing problems with the assignment operator, but you can make life a little easier by defining template versions of the various operators, helper functions to implement them, and then use inheritance.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class fixed_array {
public:
    virtual ~fixed_array() {}
    template <std::size_t K>
    fixed_array& operator+=(fixed_array<T,K> const& other) {
        for (std::size_t i=0; i<N; ++i)
            this->contents[i] += other[i];
        return *this;
    }
    template <std::size_t K>
    fixed_array& operator=(fixed_array<T,K> const& other) {
        assign_from(other);
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator[](std::size_t idx) {
        if (idx >= N)
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid index in fixed_array[]");
        return contents[idx];
    }
protected:
    template <std::size_t K>
    void assign_from(fixed_array<T,K> const& other) {
        for (std::size_t i=0; i<N; ++i)
            this->contents[i] = other[i];
    }
private:
    T contents[N];
};

template <typename T>
class fixed_2d_array: public fixed_array<T,2> {
public:
    T x_coord() const { return (*this)[0]; }
    T y_coord() const { return (*this)[1]; }
    template <std::size_t K>
    fixed_2d_array& operator=(fixed_array<T,K> const& other) {
        assign_from(other);
        return *this;
    }
};

int
main() {
    fixed_array<int,5> ary1;
    fixed_2d_array<int> ary2;
    ary2 = ary1;
    ary1 = ary2;
    ary2 += ary1;
    ary1 += ary2;
    return 0;
}
```